# Expressjs template engines are slowing requests

Tags: node.js, express, benchmarking, apachebench

I am running Apache Bench on **fresh** Expressjs generated app. I have two routes:

1)

```
router.get('/test', function(req, res, next) {
    res.send('Hello');
});
```

2)

```
router.get('/render', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index');
});
```

Called ab with: `ab -n 1000 -c 100 http://localhost:3000/test/`
and  `ab -n 1000 -c 100 http://localhost:3000/render/`

on 1) I get **~1600 req/sec**, and on 2) I get only **~380 req/sec**.
Is it standard for template engine to slow app by ~5 times?

https://github.com/asantrac/ExpressWeirdBenchmark/tree/master

Comment: It would probably be helpful if more information was given, such as Express version, node version, which template engine is being used, and what is inside the 'index' template.

Comment: @mscdex I am using node v6.9.4. Added git repository.